# What's the difference between loadfile, require, and import

Tags: lua

It seems like there are multiple ways to access one file from another.  Why would I choose one method over another?

```
local a = loadfile('foo.lua')()
local b = require 'foo.lua'
local c = import 'foo.lua'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no `import` function in the Lua standard library. Not for 5.1, 5.2 or 5.3. Maybe you're thinking of some other code that supplies this functionality; you'll have to ask the provider of that function about it.

`require` does not load `.lua` files; it loads *modules*. Exactly what `require` does is [defined by `package.loaders`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders) in 5.1 or [`package.searchers`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers) in 5.2/3. A particular module *may* be implemented as a `.lua` file, but it may also be a `.dll/.so`. Or it may be a name that's looked up in a compile-time table if the module is internal to the application. Or it could download something from the internet. Or anything at all, depending on what the `loaders`/`searchers` do.

The default `loaders`/`searchers` can load `.lua` files, but they only search through directories based on the Lua search path. This path is initialized by an environment variable, but the user can override it.

Module naming conventions also have some notion of sub-modules. You almost never put ".lua" in a module name. `require` loads modules, not files; any files loaded are a side-effect of loading a module.

Oh, and `require` caches loaded modules. Calling it again with the same module name will simply return the module that was previously loaded. If you want to reload a module, you have to effectively unload it first, which requires editing the module cache. `package.loaded` stores the module cache; setting an entry to `nil` removes it from the cache, forcing `require` to reload it.

Note that this will *not* automatically change any code that already fetched the module. Lots of Lua files will have something like `local module_name = require "module_name"` at the top of the file. You cannot reach into such scripts and change what they've already fetched. You would have to re-execute such scripts.

As such, attempting to change a module in-situ can be dangerous unless code is specifically written to expect it.

`loadfile` loads a file from the disk and compiles it as a Lua chunk. It uses the C standard library facilities to do the file loading, so paths work in accord with the C library implementation that Lua was compiled with. It returns the loaded chunk but does not execute it.

Comment: I would add that require loads a module only once and later when calling require again with same arguments it returns the return value of the module (for example return value from the lua file) or true.
loadfile instead always runs the file.

Comment: Also, `require` runs the module once. `loadfile` does not run the file.

Comment: To add to the options, theres dofile(), which is like loadfile, but also runs the chuck (loadfile only compiles the chucnk, it does not run it). I recommend this page and the next section: https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html